How to give a live Image of a tabItem in a TabView a stroke
I have a profile tabItem which shows a live image (an image from a url), I want to put a red stroke around the Image.
This video was quite helpful but the stroke isn't working on mine.
This is the implentation of the profileview TabView:
ProfileView(userProfileViewModel: UserProfileViewModel(path: $path))
                .tabItem {
                    profileViewTabItemLabel()
                }.tag(SignedTab.profile)
        
      } // End of TabView
        .onAppear {
            imageLoader.load(from: URL(string: "https://c7684bdb45.mjedge.net/wp-content/uploads/zikoko/2020/05/Artboard-2insidelife-320x320.jpg"))
                
        }

This is how I was able to get the ProfileView tabItem to show the live Image:
@ViewBuilder private func profileViewTabItemLabel() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Label {
                Text("Profile")
            } icon: {
                if let circularProfileImage = circularProfileImage {
                    Image(uiImage: circularProfileImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                        
                }  else if let image = imageLoader.image {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                        .clipShape( Circle())
                        .overlay(
                            Circle().stroke(colorTheme.primary, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Color.purple.preference(key: ImageSizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size)
                                    .overlay {
                                        Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
                                    }
                            }
                        )
                        .onPreferenceChange(ImageSizePreferenceKey.self) { size in
                            createCircularProfileImage(size: size)
                                
                        }
                        .overlay {
                            Circle().stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            Circle().stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
        }
    }
    
        private func createCircularProfileImage(size: CGSize) {
            guard let uiImage = imageLoader.image else { return }
            
            let circularImage = uiImage.createUserCircularProfileImagePicture(
                for: selectedTab,
                with: colorTheme
            )
            
            self.circularProfileImage = circularImage
        }
    }

    extension UIImage {
        func createUserCircularProfileImagePicture(for selectedTab: SignedTab, with colorTheme: ColorTheme) -> UIImage? {
            let imageSize = CGSize(width: 24, height: 24)
            
            return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize).image { imageContext in
                let imageLook = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 0), size: imageSize)
                let imageClipShape = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: imageLook)
                
                imageClipShape.stroke()
                imageClipShape.addClip()
                
                self.draw(in: imageLook)
                
                if selectedTab == .profile {
                    imageContext.cgContext.setStrokeColor(colorTheme.primary.cgColor ?? UIColor.label.cgColor)
                    imageContext.cgContext.setLineJoin(.round)
                    imageContext.cgContext.setLineCap(.round)
                    imageClipShape.lineWidth = 2
                    
                    
               }
            }
            .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        }
    }

    struct ImageSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
        static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
        static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
            value = nextValue()
        }
    }

    class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
        @Published var image: UIImage?
        
        func load(from url: URL?) {
            guard let url = url else { return }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.image = loadedImage
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }

    struct CustomAsyncImage: View {
        @StateObject var loader = ImageLoader()
        let url: URL?
        
        var body: some View {
            Group {
                if let image = loader.image {
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                } else {
                    ProgressView()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                loader.load(from: url)
            }
        }
    // end


Sorry Bro, but I'm not following you: why are you using many .stroke() modifier? Can you provide me a simplier code of your app?
Can you encapsulate your view in order to test it separately?

@GastónAntonioMontes That was me doing a trial and error, trying to see if putting them at each of this points would work. The GeometryReader plays an important role, without it, the image won't conform to the Circular shape. That's why I have so many .stroke.

I just found another question and I think that it's not possible:
1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984413/how-can-i-adjust-the-size-of-an-image-in-a-swiftui-tabitem
2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450061/image-not-resizing-in-swiftui-tabview
You can create your own bar and manually manage it.

@GastónAntonioMontes thank you for the support!
