# How can I use a custom image in my TabView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to replace the systemImage in my TabView with my own image. Every time I try this, it is too big and I cannot resize it. How can I use my custom image?

Here is my code:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Home()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                       
                        Text("Home")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                
                
            }
```

I want to replace the systemImage with an image named "Home"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image not resizing in SwiftUI TabView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450061/image-not-resizing-in-swiftui-tabview)

Comment: You can check this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874619/14476409

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-bars