# How to export 1x 2x 3x icons for iOS app from Adobe Illustrator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, adobe-illustrator

I created a 24x24 px icon in Illustrator. Then I exported it for screens in sizes 1x 2x 3x. Then I added icons to assets in Xcode.
[image]

Why do they look the same size in Xcode?
Other icons of the same size that I downloaded look larger than the other. What's the Difference? Which option is correct? Maybe I exported incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874619/2303865

Comment: You can also save just a pdf and use Universal and Single Vector

Comment: Yes, I know about the pdf method.
I just want to know why in the first case the icons look the same size. And in the second they have different sizes. Although both sets are 24,48,72

Comment: @MichelRivera you can check by selecting the image, then hitting the space bar. That will open it in quick look, so you can compare the sizes.

Comment: I know I've already done that. In the first picture, the icons are 24 -> 48 -> 72 px
And in the second picture they have  24 -> 48 -> 72 px. Why does it look like they are the same size in the first picture, but they are not?

Comment: @MichelRivera have you added the "@2x" "@3x" to their names?

Comment: Yes added. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rqUrqtXXSMVVOs_Xs-goJmXYygdo2APr?usp=sharing I uploaded these icons to google drive. Could you see what's wrong with them? Why do they visually look the same size in xcode?