# SwiftUI custom tabItem

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `TabView` like:

```
   TabView(selection: $selected) {
        HomeView(homeViewModel: homeViewModel)
        .padding()
        .tabItem {
            Image("Home").renderingMode(.original).resizable().frame(width: 23, height: 23)
        }
        .tag(1)

        SearchView()
        .padding()
        .tabItem {
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                Label("Second", systemImage: "2.circle")
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
        .tag(2)
    }
```

Im trying to customise the tabItem:

```
           .tabItem {
                Image("Home").renderingMode(.original).resizable().frame(width: 23, height: 23)
            }
```

The image is not resizing correctly, showing very big:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the renderingMode(.original)?

Comment: yes... have tried removing this, still the same issue

Comment: @GurmukhSingh You can use SF Symbols, such as using the 'house' image. Just do `Image(systemName: "house")`. Or does it need to be a custom image? If so, you may just have to resize it first in an image editor.

Comment: Try aspectRatio. .fit

Comment: you have to make your own custom tabview!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tabItem` image view cannot be resized since UIKit(https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874619/3585796)

You have two options: prepare asset with needed sizes or use an image from SF Symbols