# Remove Text from UITabBar and adjust Alignment in AppDelegate [Swift]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I cannot figure out how to remove the text from the `UITabBar` and move the images down accordingly. If it cannot be done in the **AppDelegate** then what code would I need to get the job done.

I found some code from another post on how to do this but it had to be used in the tab bar's controller.

```
for(UITabBarItem * tabBarItem in self.tabBar.items){
     tabBarItem.title = @"";
     tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
}
```

I was able convert the code from **Obj-C** to **Swift** but I could not implement it into the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the **AppDelegate**.

All help is appreciated!

For reference: [Remove tab bar item text, show only image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494130/remove-tab-bar-item-text-show-only-image/26497414)

Comment: I don't think you can access your `UITabBar` from your `AppDelegate`. Could you show us your code please ?

Comment: I just converted the above code to a for loop. I have edited it before using "UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor..."